# MobiScroll Select Preset

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

The mobiscroll documentation states

> This preset enhances a regular HTML select to select the values with a scroller. The original select is hidden, and a dummy input is visible instead. The value of the select is maintained by the preset.

The sample HTML code they provide uses inline styling to hide the original select element

```
<select name="City" id="select" style="display:none">
```

However, when I do this and setup the mobiscroll replacement to appear inline

```
$('#select').scroller({preset:'select',theme:'default',display:'inline',mode:'scroller',inputClass: 'i-
txt'});
```

I find that although the scroller appears I still end up with what looks like an input element above it.  This does not happen in their demo code but there I note that what they do is something like this

```
<div id="select_cont" style="display: none;">
<select name="City" id="select">
```

but that simply hides everything including the mobiscroll replacement.  Looking under the covers I found that calling

```
$('#select').scroller({preset:'select',theme:'default',display:'inline',mode:'scroller',inputClass: 'i-
txt'});
```

introduces a dummy input element into the DOM.

```
<input id='cities_dummy'...
```

I can get the dummy to hide  itself by issuing a

```
$('#cities_dummy').css('display','none')
```

immediately after creating the scroller.  However, I cannot understand why things are working differently in the demo code.  I have noted that they are using jQuery Mobile v 1.1.1 whilst I am using the very latest version.

Perhaps this issue is related to versions?  Or is there something else at play here? I'd much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  It is all down to the

```
inputClass:i-txt
```

bit in the scroller options settings.  In the demo code they are probably playing with this class via script depending on the value of the *display* property in the options object.  The point is this - in order to get the original select to disappear when the scroller display is set to "inline" you must define i-txt (or whatever input class you use) as

```
.i-txt{display:none}
```